# Can't add XML serialization in unit test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, xml-parsing

I somehow can't add XML serialization into a unit test. Visual studio only says that a using or an assembly is missing but I used the `using System.Xml.Serialization;`.
Visual Studio looks like this:
[image: The type or namespace name 'XmlSerializer' could not be found]
What do I have to do that I can use XMLSerializer in my unit tests?

Comment: what target framework are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.6.1

Comment: Ok, I just figured it out. I had to manually add the dll.
Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:
After at least one hour of trying to fix it, I found out that I have to add the reference manually. 
I thought system references were added automatically.